# importing functions from subfolder in windows and linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, import

I want to import a function from a file inside a subfolder.
The filename differs depending on the previous code, that's why i got the 'file' variable.

I have come up with different code for Windows and Linux.

The folder layout is like this:

```
#ls project/
file.py  subfolder
#ls project/subfolder/
subfile.py
```

file.py

```
import os
os.chdir('subfolder')
file = 'subfile'
if os.name == 'nt': #for windows
    exec('from ' + file + ' import *')
else:
    exec('from subfolder.' + file + ' import *')
print(subfunction())
```

subfile.py

```
def subfunction():
    return 1
```

This different behavior seems odd to me, since it is the same programming language on 2 different os.
Does someone have a better code example than this or can elaborate why it is like it is?

Note: on windows i got python version 3.6.5 from Anaconda and on linux Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is just the *Linux* way. I'm not sure why the *windows* approach works for you.

`os.chdir()` should not affect the path where python looks for modules to import. The path where python looks for them is located in `sys.path`.

See [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) and for further information read through [BrenBarn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/6150188).